# Class not found when using class from referenced jar

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I built a few Java desktop apps which all reference a common Java class library I also made. I'm having trouble running this setup outside of Netbeans. I copied all jars (the library and the programs) into some folder, but when I try to run any of the programs, they crash saying they cannot find some class from the common library.

I never tried this sort of scenario before... what am I doing wrong? I'd bet it has something to do with the classpath, and I'm looking into that. This is the error message:

```
D:\LAB\FIUBA\Stock84885\bin>java -jar Stock84885OrderReceiver.jar
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: core/ILogger
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: core.ILogger
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

(ILogger is a class from the common class library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include all the dependencies jars in your classpath when executing a program outside your IDE.

> ```
>    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
> ```

Try this:

```
java -cp "lib/*" com.example.Main
```

Replace lib/  with the directory in which the dependencies jars are contained and com.example.Main for the class containing the main method.

Make sure that the file Stock84885OrderReceiver.jar is contained within the classpath

Comment: I tried the full path and also "." (because it is the current dir), but I got the same error

Comment: What's the name of your main class, including packages? You'll need to use `java -cp "lib/*" com.example.Main` , being com.example.Main the class containing the main method

Comment: @dario_ramos also, include the Stock84885OrderReceiver.jar in the classpath

Comment: You sent in me the right direction. The only detail is that I had to use a full path, for instance:

`java -cp D:\LAB\Project\bin\* package.MainClass`